# How to assign to a field of nil struct in golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to assign a value to a field, but my program panics with `runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference`.

```
package main

type Node struct {
    Value int
}

func (n *Node) SetValue(value int) {
    n.Value = value
}

func main() {
    var n *Node

    n.SetValue(1)
}
```

This is reasonable since variable is nil.
But I've fount some Go internal structs are allowed to do this, e.g. `bytes.Buffer`

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "io"
import "os"

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    b.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &b)
}
```

Here is the `bytes.Buffer source code

```
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    b.lastRead = opInvalid
    m := b.grow(len(p))
    return copy(b.buf[m:], p), nil
}
```

Is it the thing only builtin structs can do or it's possible to accomplish this in my code?

**EDIT**
Here is the working example. Thanks @twotwotwo for suggestion.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Node struct {
    Value int
}

func (n *Node) SetValue(value int) {
    n.Value = value
}

func main() {
    var n Node

    n.SetValue(1)

    fmt.Println(n.Value)
}
```

Comment: Nothing special; you can do this in your code. The trick is that `b` isn't a `nil` *pointer* to `bytes.Buffer`, it's a `bytes.Buffer` *struct* with all its fields initially zeroed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The crucial thing is `var b bytes.Buffer` doesn't get you a `nil` pointer, it gets you a `bytes.Buffer` object with all its fields initialized with their zero values (in machine terms, with zero bytes). [The spec says](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) the zero value is "false for booleans, 0 for integers, 0.0 for floats, "" for strings, and nil for pointers, functions, interfaces, slices, channels, and maps"; follow that link for more detail.

It is possible to make your own structs whose zero values work and [the Go team encourages it](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_new). `struct Position { x, y int }` is an easy example and Effective Go gives a more realistic one. But note that that doesn't make *the nil pointer* work; you would still need `new(Node)` or `var n Node` to allocate the zero `Node`. Same for `bytes.Buffer`.

Another common use of zero values: wherever your users create structs of your type directly (as folks do with, say, [`http.Server`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server)), the zero value is the default for any fields they don't specify. It's the default in a lot of other places: what you get for a not-found map key, if you receive from a closed channel, and probably others.

Comment: But I didn't allocate `bytes.Buffer` neither with `new` keyword or struct literal. How come, it get's me initialized `bytes.Buffer` object.

Comment: `var T` allocates a `T`: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables (`var *T` does not allocate a `T`.)